# Task execution in Java web application

Tags: java, spring, queue, task

I'm developing Spring MVC web application. One of it's functionalities is file converting (uploading file -> converting -> storing on server). 
Some files could be too big for converting on-the-fly so I decided to put them in shared queue after upload.
Files will be converted with priority based on upload time, i.e. FIFO.

My idea is to add task to queue in controller after upload.
There would also be service executing all tasks in queue, and if empty, then wait until new task is added. I don't need scheduling - tasks should be executing always when queue is not empty.

I've read about `ExecutorService` but I didn't find any example that fit to my case.

I'd appreciate any suggestions.

**EDIT**
Thanks for answers, I need to clarify my problem:
Basically, I know how to execute tasks, I need to manage with handling the queue of tasks. User should be able to view the queue and pause, resume or remove task from queue.
My task class:

```java
public class ConvertTask implements Callable<String> {

    private Converter converter;
    private File source;
    private File target;
    private State state;
    private User user;

    public ConvertTask(Converter converter, File source, File target, User user) {
        this.converter = converter;
        this.source = source;
        this.target = target;
        this.user = user;
        this.state = State.READY;
    }

    @Override
    public String call() throws Exception {
        if (this.state == State.READY) {
            BaseConverterService converterService = ConverterUtils.getConverterService(this.converter);
            converterService.convert(this.source, this.target);
            MailSendServiceUtil.send(user.getEmail(), target.getName());
            return "success";
        }
        return "task not ready";
    }
}
```

I also created class responsible for managing queue/tasks followed by your suggestions:

```java
@Component
public class MyExecutorService {
    private LinkedBlockingQueue<ConvertTask> converterQueue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();

    private ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

    public void add(ConvertTask task) throws InterruptedException {
        converterQueue.put(task);
    }

    public void execute() throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
        while (!converterQueue.isEmpty()) {
            ConvertTask task = converterQueue.peek();
            Future<String> statusFuture = executorService.submit(task);
            String status = statusFuture.get();
            converterQueue.take();
        }
    }
}
```

My point is, how to execute tasks if queue is not empty and resume when new task is added and queue was previously empty. I think of some code that fits in `add(ConvertTask task)` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edited after question updates**

You don't need to create any queue for the tasks since the `ThreadPoolExecutor` implementation has its own queue. Here's the source code of Oracle's `Java 8` implementation of `newSingleThreadExecutor()` method:

```
public static ExecutorService newSingleThreadExecutor() {
    return new FinalizableDelegatedExecutorService
        (new ThreadPoolExecutor(1, 1,
                                0L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS,
                                new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>()));
}
```

So you just submit a new task directly and it's getting queued by the `ThreadPoolExecutor`

```
@Component
public class MyExecutorService {
    private ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

    public void add(ConvertTask task) throws InterruptedException {
        Future<String> statusFuture = executorService.submit(task);
    }
}
```

If you're worried about the bounds of your queue, you can create a queue  instance explicitly and supply it to a `ThreadPoolExecutor` constructor.

```
private executorService = new ThreadPoolExecutor(1, 1, 
                 0L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, new LinkedBlockingQueue<>(MAX_SIZE));
```

Please note that I have removed the line

```
String status = statusFuture.get();
```

because `get()` call is blocking. If you have this line in the same thread where you submit, your code is not asynchronous anymore. You should store the `Future` objects and check them asynchronously in a different thread. Or you can consider using `CompletableFuture` introduced in `Java 8`. Check out [this post](http://www.nurkiewicz.com/2014/11/executorservice-10-tips-and-tricks.html).

Comment: Can I somehow get the queue that `ExecutorService` adds tasks to? I need to have functionality to view the queue and modify it's elements.

Comment: The interface `ExecutorService` does not know antything about the queues, but the implementation `ThreadPoolExecutor` does. It has a method `getQueue()`.  You can also provide a queue instance created by you. It's in my answer.

Comment: Thanks, I think it should will be ok. Unfortunately, `getQueue()` returns `FutureTask` so I need to get `ConvertTask` from `callable` field using reflection, as shown [here](http://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue228.html)

Comment: Why would you need to manipulate your submitted queue? This would be a poor separation of concerns. It has a bad smell. If you need to pre-process your tasks, you can do this before submitting them to your converter. Instead of letting different components meddle with each other business - chain the processing. If you have multiple asynchronous steps - use several executors.

Comment: As i wrote before, I need to be able to present the queue in view with possibility to remove tasks. Example:
User A adds 5 tasks to the queue. User B also adds 5 tasks.
Now admin can view whole queue and remove any task he wants.

Comment: The administrator UI would have a lag presenting data and submitting the selected candidates for removal. As executors crunch the tasks asynchronously, and probably very fast, chances for a human admin to catch anything in the queue will be random. Sounds like a bad idea. Again, I think you should chain the operations. Make some stop-filter before submitting. Store the task IDs in a hahset to prevent duplications and remove them when task is done. Something like that.

Answer (score 0):

After upload you should return response immediately. The client can't wait for resource too long. However you can change it in the client settings. Anyway if you are running a background task you can do it without interacting with the client or notify the client while execution is in progress. This is an example of callable demo used by the executor service

```
/**
 * Created by Roma on 17.02.2015.
 */
class SumTask implements Callable<Integer> {
  private int num = 0;
  public SumTask(int num){
    this.num = num;
  }
  @Override
  public Integer call() throws Exception {
    int result = 0;
    for(int i=1;i<=num;i++){
      result+=i;
    }
    return result;
  }
}

public class CallableDemo {

  Integer result;
  Integer num;

  public Integer getNumValue() {
    return 123;
  }
  public Integer getNum() {
    return num;
  }

  public void setNum(Integer num) {
    this.num = num;
  }

  public Integer getResult() {
    return result;
  }

  public void setResult(Integer result) {
    this.result = result;
  }

  ExecutorService service =  Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

  public String  execute() {
    try{

      Future<Integer> future = service.submit(new SumTask(num));
      result = future.get();
      //System.out.println(result);
      service.shutdown();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return "showlinks";
  }
}
```